# Abort AsyncTask within the AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

How to cancel a AsyncTask from a ProgressDialog implemented within this AsyncTask.

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
{
    try 
    {
        FTPHelper ftpHelper = new FTPHelper(_context);
        ftpHelper.SincronizarArquivos();
    }
    catch...

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() 
{
    _dialog.setMessage("Aguarde, sincronizando arquivos...");
    _dialog.setCancelable(false); 
    _dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    { 
        @Override 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            // This not works for cancel AsyncTask
            cancel(true);
            ...
```

Since there is no loop in doInBackground (Void ... params) has as I cancel or return. How can I cancel AsyncTask from ProgressDialog?

Comment: It seems you should implement some flag to be checked inside `FTPHelper.SincronizarArquivos` method and then just set that flag on you `onClick` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Both the dialog and the AsyncTask have a 'cancel' method, so when you call cancel in the dialog it cancels the dialog.

The solution is for the dialog to call the cancel function of the AsyncTask. From the code in the question I can't quite infer the way the dialog and the task are linked in the code, but in essence, if ...

```
AsyncTask myAT;
```

Then within the dialog:

```
myAT.cancel();
```

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
MyAsyncTask.this.cancel(true);
```

inside the `Dialog`.

Here `MyAsyncTask` is the name of your `AsyncTask` subclass.

NOTE: This will work (only) if the `Dialog` was instantiated inside the `AsyncTask`